# Flutter set state not working when app restarts

Tags: flutter

I have a file Login.dart I had added a function to a button in flutter.

```
 onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                username = usernameController.text;
                isUserLoggedIn = true;
              });
              print(username);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
```

As this function show that on button is pressed it will set isUserLoggedIn = true. Its working fine and value of the boolean is changing fine.

Now in my main.dart

```
class _NavigationPageState extends State<NavigationPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: isUserLoggedIn == false ? IntroAuthScreen() : HomePage(),
);
}
}
```

So now as the value of isUserLoggedIn is setted to true my code should redirect me to HomePage() but when i restart my app it still redirect me to IntroAuthScreen()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you restart the app, isUserLoggedIn will revert back to its original value. You can save your app settings with [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: ok I had imported this package. so please can you show me sample code of how to achive that I want to?

Comment: here's a good tutorial for shared_preferences package you can follow: https://dev.to/simonpham/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-effortlessly-3e29